# why wait.until doesn't work in selenium but thread.sleep does?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

In a piece of code instead of

```
Thread.sleep (4000);
```

I want use

```
from wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.xpath ("// div [@class = \" x-tool-img x-tool-expand-bottom x-rtl \ "]")));
```

and i see error but using Thread.sleep I do not have an error message and the code is easily passed i don't no why not pass with  wait.until ??

Thank you for your guide

Comment: What is the error? and please post the real code, this is not valid Java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The valid syntax of wait can be found here:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Valid Format.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement e4 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ElementtobeVisible));
```

or Check out this [Link](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html), it will be Helpful.